# Why do these two updates on different tables cause a deadlock?

Tags: postgresql

This is happening in PostgreSQL 9.4.1.

I have two tables which are simplified for this question.

```
core_deck
+-------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Column      | Type                     | Modifiers                                                 |
|-------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------|
| id          | integer                  |  not null default nextval('core_deck_id_seq'::regclass) |
| status      | character varying(32)    |  not null                                                 |
| account_id  | integer                  |  not null                                                 |
+-------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+

core_membership
+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Column         | Type                  | Modifiers                                                                   
|----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| id             | integer               |  not null default nextval('core_membership_id_seq'::regclass)               
| account_id     | integer               |  not null                                                                   
| visit_count    | smallint              |  not null                                                                   
+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Each table has a foreign key to a `core_account` table.

I am seeing deadlocks like this:

```
Process 43189 waits for ShareLock on transaction 2929976445; blocked by process 3982.
Process 3982 waits for ShareLock on transaction 2929976441; blocked by process 43189.
Process 43189: UPDATE "core_deck" SET "account_id" = 10094676, "status" = 'COMPLETED' WHERE "core_deck"."id" = 10563730
Process 3982: UPDATE "core_membership" SET "account_id" = 10094676, "visit_count" = 9 WHERE "core_membership"."id" = 13537206
```

I don't understand why this is happening because the foreign key is not being changed and nothing in the account table is being updated.

Your help would be appreciated.

**Update 07-18**: The SQL above shows the foreign key being set to the same value it already is. This is because Django apparently sets all the values, not just the ones that are being changed, during update.

**Update 07-19**: Here is another example based on the answer I was given yesterday. As shown I unfortunately cannot reproduce this lock problem

```
create table parent (id int PRIMARY key);
create table child_1 (id int primary key, parent_id int references parent, name varchar(32));
create table child_2 (id int primary key, parent_id int references parent, name varchar(32));
create view pg_my_locks as select relname, mode from pg_locks l join pg_class c on l.relation = c.oid where relname not like 'pg\_%';

begin;
update child_1 set parent_id = 1, name = 'Foo' where id = 1
update child_2 set parent_id = 1, name = 'Bar' where id = 1
select * from pg_my_locks
+--------------+------------------+
| relname      | mode             |
|--------------+------------------|
| child_2_pkey | RowExclusiveLock |
| child_2      | RowExclusiveLock |
| child_1_pkey | RowExclusiveLock |
| child_1      | RowExclusiveLock |
+--------------+------------------+
end;
```

Comment: SET "account_id" = 10094676 <-- isn't this changing the foreign key?

Comment: But the account_id was already set. It's just redundant. Sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: As I understood it PostgreSQL has optimizations in its locking manager to detect if the foreign key is set to the same value. http://blog.nordeus.com/dev-ops/postgresql-locking-revealed.htm

Comment: @seonghuhn: Updating the same record twice within one transaction will trigger a re-check of all foreign keys, even if no FK fields were involved in the update (a [known issue](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/14714.1266372676%40sss.pgh.pa.us), though apparently not one they plan on resolving). Could that be the case here?

Comment: Hi Nick. I am not sure if that applies. I am not updating the same record twice. I am aware of that issue which is what I believe kiln is pointing to.